# Why does dropdown-toggle (bootstrap) not work on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

I do not understand why the following piece of code in my view (title bar) does not work on heroku.

It seems to work fine on both development and production on my local server. Once i push to heroku, the html generated is also good. All other bootstrap elements seem to work. However, this dropdown link does not seem to work

```
    <% if current_user.present? %>


                <div id = "account" class=" dropdown">

                        <a href='#' class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <span>Account</span> <b class="caret"></b>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                            <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
                            <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li>
                                <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                </div>
                <% end %>
```

The HTML generated:

```
                <div id = "account" class=" dropdown">

                        <a href='#' class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <span>Account</span> <b class="caret"></b>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                            <li><a href="/users/1">Profile</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/users/1/edit">Settings</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="/signout" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Sign out</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                </div>

                </div>
```

my app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

```
 * = require custom
```

my app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

I am pretty new to heroku. So i am not aware of how to debug such an error. How can this be sorted out how i can debug such an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some strange bug in rails: my application.js was initially:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require bootstrap
```

I had to reorder it and move bootstrap ahead of jquery

Modified application.js

```
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
```

And then I had to run

```
heroku run rake assets:reset
heroku run rake assets:precompile
```

Now it works

Answer (score 1):

Well, I had the same problem. The dropdown worked on local but not on Heroku.

I had tried to reorder the //=jquery and //=bootstrap and reorder back again and again. I also ran asset precompile method. However, it still didn't work in my situation.

Then I compared an app I wrote before, and I found that there might be the conflict between 'bootstrap' and 'bootstrap-spockets'. The dropdown menu worked if either of them were removed. So I removed 'bootstrap' finally. I am not sure if it will cause any further problems but so far it's fine.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Remove bootstrap and leave bootstrap-sprockets. See the https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#a-ruby-on-rails toward the bottom of that part of the chapter about ruby on rails. It refers to this issue on bootstrap-sass: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/issues/829#issuecomment-75153827

Comment: Also there is not problem doing this, because `//= require bootstrap` loads in a combined version of all the javascript, while `//= require bootstrap-sprockets` does the same thing but loads in the individual files. In production this does not matter since everything is compiled into one file anyway. So this bug is caused by Bootstrap javascript being included twice.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to precompile your assets

```
heroku run rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: i tried it now, and then ran the "heroku restart --a app_name" just in case. It still seems to not work. Is there anything else that i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

you can add to your file application.js :

```
//= require bootstrap/dropdown
```

So, your file would be :

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap/dropdown
```